# Cucumber. Get property using System.getProperty()

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I need to get the system property when running cucumber, but

```
private final String browserName = System.getProperty("browser");
```

eturns null

I'm using maven, cucumber, selenium and junit
I need to get the system properties for cucumber from pom.xml . What am I doing for this.
In pom.xml I specify the property to the file

```
<properties>
<browser>firefox</browser>
</properties>
```

and I use it in the plugin

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
 <configuration>
 <systemPropertyVariables>
 <browser>${browser}</browser>
 </systemPropertyVariables>
 </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Next, I run the script in the file.feature and trying to get verified

```
private final String browserName = System.getProperty("browser");
```

But the browser variable returns null. I don't understand why

Comment: Are you running your tests with Maven or through an IDE?

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the value in `systemPropertyVariables`?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `systemPropertyVariables` and run `mvn test -Dbrowser=firefox`?

Comment: I run tests both using maven using commands and using the IDE via cucumber feature files.

The browser value is already set in systemPropertyVariables.

If you delete systemPropertyVariables and run `mvn test -Dbrowser=firefox` , the firefox browser will be launched, because the value passed through the flag will be available in the system properties for cucumber.

The problem is that when running through maven commands, the system property is available. But it is not available if you run tests through cucumber feature files.

Comment: That is to be expected. When you run the Cucumber files through your IDE you run them through `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main`. This is completely independent from Maven.  You will have to look at the run configurations in your IDE to see how you can apply system properties to those executions.